# bash, extract string before a colon

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, substring

If I have a file with rows like this

```
/some/random/file.csv:some string
/some/random/file2.csv:some string2
```

Is there some way to get a file that only has the first part before the colon, e.g.

```
/some/random/file.csv
/some/random/file2.csv
```

I would prefer to just use a bash one liner, but perl or python is also ok.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

```
cut -d: -f1
```

or

```
awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

or

```
sed 's/:.*//'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to list only the names of folders that changed in a git diff starting with a particular pattern

Comment: Lol I'm an idiot for forgetting about cut, just spent 10 minutes trying to do this regex and then literally facepalmed when I read your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 123):

Another pure BASH way:

```
> s='/some/random/file.csv:some string'
> echo "${s%%:*}"
/some/random/file.csv
```

Comment: this does not work as expected if there are more than one colons in the variable, since it cuts at the last occurrence and not as expected the first... use <code>${s%%:*}<code> instead

Comment: That's right `%%` will suit better. It is edited now.

Comment: Works for me to strip only the wanted info from a list of words, one at a time, with the format [info]_mapping.json. `echo "${s%%_mapping.json}"`

Comment: To target some other character, e.g. `.`: `"${s%%.*}"`. To target any of several characters, e.g. `.` or `-`:  `"${s%%[.-]*}"`.

Answer (score 42):

Try this in pure bash:

```
FRED="/some/random/file.csv:some string"
a=${FRED%:*}
echo $a
```

[Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) is some documentation that helps.

Comment: awesome answer much appreciated

Comment: Note that a single `%`  only extracts to the *first* colon; use `%%` to extract to the *last* colon.

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite: `%%` extracts up to the first, `%` to the last.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me you guys can try it out

```
INPUT='ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash'
SUBSTRING=$(echo $INPUT| cut -d: -f1)
echo $SUBSTRING
```

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked so many times so that a user with over 1000 points ask for this is some strange
But just to show just another way to do it:

```
echo "/some/random/file.csv:some string" | awk '{sub(/:.*/,x)}1'
/some/random/file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another pure Bash solution:

```
while IFS=':' read a b ; do
  echo "$a"
done < "$infile" > "$outfile"
```

Comment: +1 (with a minor edit); this is the standard way to read delimited text from a file in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `basename` with:

```
basename /some/random/file.csv:some :some
```