# How to extract everything before the first undersore in a string?

Tags: string, bash

I have files that are named like this:

```
MG-AB-110_S101_R2_001.fastq.gz, MG-AB-109_S100_R1_001.fastq.gz...
```

I am trying to extract everything before the first underscore so that I get: MG-AB-110, MG-AB-109...

I tried to do this:

```
name="MG-AB-110_S101_R2_001.fastq.gz"
base_name=${name%%.*}
echo $base_name
MG-AB-110_S101_R2_001
```

and this:

```
base_name=${name%%(.*?)_.* }
echo $base_name
MG-AB-110_S101_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I need these base names to match base names in another folder, so the above regex would be part of this loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in test1/*.gz; do
    base_name=${name%%.*}

    if [ -f "test2/$base_name" ]; then
        cat "$name" "test2/$base_name" >"all_combined/$base_name"
    else
         printf 'No file in test2 corresponds to "%s"\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: With a regex: `[[ $name =~ ([^_]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: See: [bash, extract string before a colon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20348097/3776858)

Comment: I removed that UPDATE and I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994464/how-to-match-files-in-different-folders-by-partial-file-name-and-concatenate-the

Answer (score 6):

With bash and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
name="MG-AB-110_S101_R2_001.fastq.gz"
echo "${name%%_*}"
```

Output:

```
MG-AB-110
```

Comment: That page is a parsing bible. Bookmark it.